# Capturing text within a page without refreshing on enter

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text box and input button on an HTML form. I want to simply capture the user input text and pass it to a Javascript function to alter settings on the same page without refreshing. Everything I try ends up refreshing the page and losing my settings. Don't need to submit the input. Of course, the button is no problem, just the enter key. I have found a lot of good info here, but still no success.
Here is my code very much simplified:

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="codeform" >
<input name= "CodeTextBox" type="text" id="keywords" MAXLENGTH="20" SIZE="20" onkeypress="handleEnter(this, event, this.form)" />
<INPUT NAME="CodeButton" VALUE="click button" TYPE=BUTTON onClick=PromocodeValid(this.form)>
</FORM>
<script> 
function PromocodeValid(form)
{
   alert( form.CodeTextBox.value );
}
</script>
<script> 
function handleEnter(inField, e, form) {
var charCode;
  if(e && e.which){
    charCode = e.which;
  }else if(window.event){
    e = window.event;
    charCode = e.keyCode;
  }
  if(charCode == 13) {
    PromocodeValid(form)
    return false; 
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you must put your input text inside a form you could use onSubmit="return false;"

Comment: Thank you @jambriz, but I have inserted that into my form with the same result. When the enter key is pressed within the text box, the page reloads and the text is lost. There must be something very basic I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Sorry, That did do the trick! I wasn't calling the "return false" in the form itself, but in a function outside of the form.